# Make a copy of data held by $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a few variables in a `$scope` and I want to create a new object that contains those variables, without all the internal stuff that Angular holds in `$scope`.  I don't necessarily know the names of the `$scope` variables that I want to copy.

Something like:

```
$scope.a = "Test";
$scope.b = {x: 1, y: 2};
$scope.c = 99;
//possibly other unknown variables

var obj = angular.copy_without_angular_stuff($scope);
```

How can I get just the relevant data?

Comment: so you want have `obj` hold values of a, b and c? or you want `obj` to hold `$scope`?

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary I want obj to be an object with the keys `a`, `b` and `c`, and the values of those keys.

Comment: I don't know if this is feasible for your amount of data, but you could instead just assign `a, b, c` to another object like `$scope.obj = {a: "test", b: {x: 1, y: 2}, c: 99};`  Then you just need to look at the `$scope.obj`.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I don't know what are the variables names in the `$scope` that I want to copy.

Comment: but why you need this?

Comment: so you could use anything without `angular.copy()`?? I've an alternative which is `angular.extend()`, just clarifying as u say `angular.copy_without_angular_stuff($scope)`

Comment: @Grundy The `why` would take a few paragraphs, but, basically, I want to interpolate some data in a directive, then interpolate against the variables in the parent scope of the directive.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary I don't see how `extend()` would help here. That will, best case scenario, create another copy of `$scope` with all the stuff that I don't want/care about.

Comment: hey, there is a difference between angular.copy and angular.extend, angular.copy() makes a deep copy of the source object being passed, whereas angular.extend() would make a shallow copy. Deep copy- source and destination point to different objects. Shallow copy- source and destination point to same reference of object. SO, using angular.extend() would not be costly

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary I don't care if it is constly or not. I want an object that contains *only* variables not created by Angular.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
this
```

instead of

```
$scope
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/azXBRc1LlYJqbc6fcwJu?p=preview)

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', function(){
  var vm = this;

  vm.a = 'test';

  vm.b = {a: 'a', b: 'b'};

  vm.c = 123;

  var obj = vm;

});
```

In my view, I displayed each of the values attached to VM. As well as VM, where it shows just a, b, and c as the objects attached to VM.

```
vm.a: {{vm.a}}
<br/>
vm.b: {{vm.b}}
<br/>
vm.c: {{vm.c}}
<br/>

vm: {{vm}}
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't get to choose whether it's on $scope or not, then here is a  [new plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/azXBRc1LlYJqbc6fcwJu?p=preview) that uses $scope.

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('My2ndCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = 'test';

  $scope.b = {a: 'a', b: 'b'};

  $scope.c = 123;

  var obj = {};


  for(var k in $scope) {
    if($scope.hasOwnProperty(k) && k.indexOf('$') < 0) {
      obj[k] = $scope[k]
    }
  }
 console.log(obj);
});
```

The obj is then:

```
{a: "test", b: Object, c: 123}
```

Comment: I don't own/control the `$scope` from which I'm trying to get the variables, so I can't use `this`.

Comment: Updated my answer with a new plnkr using $scope

Answer (score 1):

`$scope` object have a few interval properties, that starts from `$`, so as workaround you can simply copy just properties that not start from `$`, or even create map for internal `$scope` properties and if property not in map - copied it.
**Note:** list of internal properties can be different in different angular versions

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {
    function clearCopy(scope) {
      var dest = {};
      for (var i in scope) {
        if (scope.hasOwnProperty(i) && i[0] !== '$' && i !== 'this') {
          dest[i] = scope[i];
        }
      }
      return dest;
    }
    $scope.a = "Test";
    $scope.b = {
      x: 1,
      y: 2
    };
    $scope.c = 99;

    $scope.copy1 = clearCopy($scope);
  })
  .controller('ctrl2', function($scope) {
    function clearCopy(scope) {
      var internalProperiesMap = {
          $$ChildScope: true,
          $$childHead: true,
          $$childTail: true,
          $$listenerCount: true,
          $$listeners: true,
          $$nextSibling: true,
          $$prevSibling: true,
          $$watchers: true,
          $$watchersCount: true,
          $id: true,
          $parent: true
        },
        dest = {};
      for (var i in scope) {
        if (scope.hasOwnProperty(i) && !internalProperiesMap[i]) {
          dest[i] = scope[i];
        }
      }
      return dest;
    }
    $scope.a = "Test";
    $scope.b = {
      x: 1,
      y: 2
    };
    $scope.c = 99;
    $scope.copy2 = clearCopy($scope);
  }).controller('ctrl3', function($scope) {
    function clearCopy(scope) {
      var internalProperiesMap = {
        $$ChildScope: true,
        $$childHead: true,
        $$childTail: true,
        $$listenerCount: true,
        $$listeners: true,
        $$nextSibling: true,
        $$prevSibling: true,
        $$watchers: true,
        $$watchersCount: true,
        $id: true,
        $parent: true
      };
      return Object.keys(scope).reduce(function(acc, el) {
        if (el[0] !== '$' && typeof scope[el] !== "function") {
          acc[el] = scope[el];
        }
        return acc;
      }, {});
    }
    $scope.a = "Test";
    $scope.b = {
      x: 1,
      y: 2
    };
    $scope.c = 99;
    $scope.fun = function(d){return d;};

    $scope.copy3 = clearCopy($scope);
  console.log($scope.copy3);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl1'>copy 1: {{copy1}}</div>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl2'>copy 2: {{copy2}}</div>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl3'>copy 3: {{copy3}}</div>
</div>
```

But anyway it seems like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I'm actually suggesting this. You should really refactor your code so you don't have to do it. Regardless if you actually need to do this...

```
$scope.test = 4;
var copiedObject = {};
for(var key in $scope){
    if(key[0] != '$' && key != 'this'){
        copiedObject[key] = $scope[key];
    }
}
console.log(copiedObject);
```

This will loop through all the keys and rip out the angular specific stuff. Here's a jsFiddle of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/n8bz4L7e/

**Note:** If you have references in the object, or other $scope variables saved for some reason this will copy those over as well. As someone mentioned elsewhere, this is most likely an XY Problem.

Comment: also in `1.4` version `$scope` does not have property `this` :-)

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the next best thing I can get. Nevertheless, I'd add some more type-checking to the condition. `if($scope.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== "this" && key.indexOf("$") !== 0 && typeof($scope[key]) !== "function")`.

Comment: @alexandernst, `key.indexOf("$") !== 0` not needed, methinks, `key[0] !== '$'` enought and simplest

Comment: @Grundy they are the same thing. But yes, yours could be a little bit faster as it doesn't involve calling another function, but just getting the first char.

Comment: @alexandernst also why you want filter functions too?

Comment: @Grundy because I want values, not functions. The newly created object will be used to interpolate a string, so II don't need functions.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be copy the properties of one object, in this case $scope, into another object:

```
for(var k in $scope) {
  secondObject[k] = $scope[k];
}
```

Comment: That will return all the stuff that Angular stores in `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with using underscore you can do

```
var obj = _.extendOwn({}, $scope);
```

Otherwise just manually copy the properties in a loop

```
var obj = {};

for(var k in $scope) {
    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call($scope, k)) {
        obj[k] = $scope[k];   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read carefully the question. I don't know the names of the variables.

Comment: That's a lot easier. Updated my answer.

Comment: That won't work either as it will return all the stuff that Angular stores in the `$scope`. I want only the variables that don't belong to Angular.

Comment: So, if everything is added to $scope, how do you know which properties belong to you? The only other way to do it is to remove everything you know for a fact is going to be in scope

Answer (score 0):

I am omitting any functions on scope or any angular variables(which tend to start with `$`), also injecting $rootScope such that no inherited properties from `$rootScope` to `$scope` would get copied to the new object, `obj` and have come up with this,

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
   $scope.a = "Test";
$scope.b = {x: 1, y: 2};
$scope.c = 99;
var obj = {};
angular.extend(obj, $scope);
console.log("obj is "+obj);
for(var k in $scope) {
    if(!(Object.hasOwnProperty.call($rootScope, k))) {
if(typeof $scope[k] != "function")
if(k.indexOf("$") != 0){
        obj[k] = $scope[k]; 
console.log("key is "+k);
console.log("value is "+obj[k]);  
    }
}
}
});
</script>
```